# Selecting distinct values from a single column excluding Nulls

Tags: sql, vba

Why does these two statements return Null values in the `combobox`?

This returns Null values:

```
str = "SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL"
Me.comboList.RowSource = str
```

This also still returns Null values:

```
str = "SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL " & _
"UNION " & _
"SELECT ColumnName FROM TableNamek WHERE ColumnName IS NOT NULL"
Me.comboList.RowSource = str
```

I want to return DISTINCT values ONLY excluding Nulls.
How do I fix it? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested the queries manually?

Comment: @norie Yes I have!

Comment: These do not return `NULL` values.  Perhaps your combo box is getting the `NULL`s from somewhere else.  Perhaps you have a string `'NULL'` in the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is great news to me. I tried to investigate the data but could find any `'NULL '`. I will try `IFNULL` function and see what I get. By the Way any advice of the UNION Query vs the SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT is completely different from UNION, so it's not really possible to compare them. It's not really clear why you would use UNION without knowing what your data is and what you are expecting to appear in the combo box.

Comment: I see, I have ended up with `"SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE Len(ColumnName)>=1"`